# unix scripting to grep the selection date range?

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, backup, progress-db

Is there a script available that can pull the PROGRESS BACKUP STATUS INFO from the log file?
I did a grep on “BACKUP” and it pulls the correct information, but unfortunately there is no time date stamp associated. we are using progress version 9.1D

The end goal would look like this.

Selection Date Range:

```
Start Date: 07/6/2018    
End Date: 7/7/2018
```

Output:

```
Date: Mon July 6 20:00 2018    
20:03:28 BACKUP 10: Full Backup Started    
20:51:44 BACKUP 10: Full Backup Successfully Completed

Date: Mon July 7 20:00 2018    
20:03:28 BACKUP 10: Full Backup Started    
20:51:44 BACKUP 10: Full Backup Successfully Completed
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. This site does not create code for you.

Comment: Developers do not live by grep alone. Tom is right: a one-liner with piping grep would probably not solve this. You'll need to write an entire script to get this to work. I imagine you'd want to use cut, sed, and/or awk if you're locked into doing this with a shell script. You could also accomplish this by reading the file into Progress.

Answer (score 2):

No.  There is no simple "grep" of the log file from version 9 or earlier that will reveal this information.

Prior to version 10 log file entries only contain the time.  Not the date.  When the day rolls over an entry is written but there are many situations where that date will not be available even for more complex parsing than a simple grep.

Bonus answer: version 9 is ancient, obsolete and unsupported.  You should upgrade.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that about v9. While your bonus answer is valid, but poor asker may have his hands tied by with legacy code. Lastly, using the last modified timestamp on the file and counting back through the file, a script could be written to determine date.